# How to affect all using tag name

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using JavaScript, how can you affect all elements with the same tag name?
I have tried `getElementByTagName` and `querySelectorAll` however, I could only target them one at a time. Is there any way to target them all at once? You know... besides using `ById` or `ByClass`.

And as a side question, can anyone show me a link to the how to affect css element variables using JavaScript? I forgot the tag and the question itself but it had a css code like so: -

```
#someID{
width: JavaScriptVar;
height: JavaScriptVar;
...
}
```

Sorry, I forgot the title of that question.

Comment: Use `getElementsByTagName` (note, not `getElementByTagName`) and then iterate over the returned array, applying some function inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea!

One small correction. It should be `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementByTagName`.

Store the result in a variable and iterate with a for loop.

Here's a simple example.

```js
var fruits = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    fruits[i].className = "gold";
}
```

```css
.gold { background: gold }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Mangos</li>
  <li>Pineapples</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much. and to be honest, i didn't think of that at all :/